Microsoft SQL server does not update data that insert into with Python
I am trying to update SQL Server table through Python. But unfortunately it does not update.
I get message successful but no data was updated.
If I call the same SQL script from within SQL Server, it updates correctly.
Let me show you my script: this is my Python code:
            import pyodbc
            import pandas as pd
            import sys
            records = [
                ['22DTHA13', 'CNTT khóa 22 lớp 4', 60],
                ['22DTHA14', 'CNTT khóa 22 lớp 5', 70],
            ]
            server = 'GIGABYTECUAT\\SQLEXPRESS'
            database = 'BAI02_QLSV1'
            username = ''
            password = ''
            connection_String = f'DRIVER={{SQL Server}};SERVER={server};DATABASE = {database};UID={username};password = {password};TRUST_CONNECTION = yes;'

            try:
                conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_String)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                print("Task is terminated")
                sys.exit()
            else:
                cusor = conn.cursor()

            insert_statement = """
                INSERT INTO LOP VALUES (?, ?, ?)
            """
            try:
                for record in records:
                    print(record)
                    cusor.execute(insert_statement, record)
                cusor.execute("SELECT * FROM LOP WHERE SISO >=50")
                rows = cusor.fetchall()
                for row in rows:
                    print(row)
                cusor.commit()
            except Exception as e:
                #cusor.rollback()
                print(f'Error: {e}')
                #print("transaction rolled back")
            else:
                print("record inserted successfully")
                cusor.commit()
                cusor.close()
            finally:
                
                if conn:
                    print('connection closed')
                    conn.close()

            

Data is updated in terminal but it's not in LOP table in MSSM

What is "MSSM"? That isn't an acronym I'm familiar with.

khóa is Vietnamese for lock. lớp = class.

The default python connector does not automatically commit any transactions. You call a cursor.commit() after your select, which is not neccesary, but not within the loop that executes the insert transactions.
You only need to call commit if changes are being made to the database by your query (insert, update, alter).
try:
    for record in records:
        print(record)
        cusor.execute(insert_statement, record)
        cusor.commit()
    cusor.execute("SELECT * FROM LOP WHERE SISO >=50")
    rows = cusor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
except Exception as e:
    #cusor.rollback()
    print(f'Error: {e}')
    #print("transaction rolled back")

By moving the commit into the loop it should actually commit all the insert.

For best performance the commit should come after the loop, not for each row.  Commit requires a physical IO, and when placed after the loop, all the changes can be batched into the minimum number of physical disk writes.

I got it guys. I tried both ways but it didn't work. :<

Try calling cursor.commit() after executing the insert statement within the "for record in records". You're calling it after the select statement, only.

I tried it but it didn't work. I think that the problem is my SQL server
